# magick-baseconfig.h is missing

Tags: c++, windows, imagemagick

I installed ImageMagick's [API](https://github.com/ImageMagick) (both ImageMagick and ImageMagick-Windows) and built ImageMagick-Windows per instructions. I am now trying to use a C++ [project](https://www.ogldev.org/index.html) that uses Magick++.

I altered that project's include directories to find Magick++'s various include files, including `magick-config.h`. But `magick-config.h` includes another file `magick-baseconfig.h`, which doesn't exist anywhere in either ImageMagick's API or ImageMagick-Windows's. It expects `magick-baseconfig.h` to be in that same subfolder (MagickCore). So: how can this file be generated?

Comment: `git grep magick-baseconfig` and then follow the breadcrumbs would probably be a good start to working it out...

Comment: Thanks! The result I got was: not a git repository. So I tried making a directory, going into it, `git clone https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git`, then `git grep magick-baseconfig`. It returned no results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be:

- Forget about ImageMagick-main and use ImageMagick-Windows-main.
- go into build/config
- load and run the .sln file there.

This created magick-baseconfig.h.
README.md has further instructions.